# Facebook appends parameters to a url when it is liked

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-likebox, facebook-wall

I’ve recently added a Facebook like button to a site of mine and all seems to work fine except that the post on my Facebook wall has a url with a load of parameters appended to the url.

Example: http://domain.com/this-is-a-new-post-to-test-the-url?fb_action_ids=1403388974344336068&fb_action_types=og.likes&fb_ref=sp_facebook_57&fb_source=aggregation&fb_aggregation_id=247881481237582

I have set the open graph meta tag  but this does not seem to make any difference.

What I find interesting is that some pages I’ve liked (on a different domain) don’t have these parameters appended to it.

The question is: how to “sanitise” the url on my Facebook wall so it looks like http://domain.com/this-is-a-new-post-to-test-the-url and NOT like http://domain.com/this-is-a-new-post-to-test-the-url?fb_action_ids=1403388974344336068&fb_action_types=og.likes&fb_ref=sp_facebook_57&fb_source=aggregation&fb_aggregation_id=247881481237582

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook adds these parameters so that website owners can keep track of where incoming traffic from Facebook originated and can not be removed.